# C# Email sending error on Godaddy server

Tags: c#

I have one web application which hosted on Godaddy server. I am stuck with Failure sending mail error. I place my code here

```
public void Mailing()
{
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
 try
{
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("mailadress@server.net");
    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.To.Add("toresive@server.com");
    message.CC.Add("ccresive@server.com");

    message.Subject = "Hello client";
    message.IsBodyHtml= true;
    string body = "Hello!<br> How are you?";

    message.Body = body;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
    smtpClient.Port = 465;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailadress@server.net", "Password");
   // AdvancedIntellect.Ssl.SslSocket ssl = new AdvancedIntellect.Ssl.SslSocket();
    smtpClient.Send(message);
    smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label2.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

}
```

But I got error

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 68.178.232.62:25 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
>   Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async,
>   Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Form1.Mailing() in
>   c:\inetpub\vhosts\pay2school.net\httpdocs\IPTest\Admin\Form1.aspx.cs:line
>   139

I am rely fade up with this error. :( 
I was change my SMTP server with smtpout.secureserver.net but not work.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually smtp is on port 25 and that port is open. Are you sure 465 is correct? It appears to be unavailable. Can you `telnet relay-hosting.secureserver.net 465` to verify connectivity?

Comment: Hi! Yup Godaddy gives me this port. But before that I was already use 25, 3535, 80 numbers of ports. But these all ports are sending same error.

Comment: I can access port 25 on that server but not port 465.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. I am also use port 25 now error is change. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at Form1.Mailing() .

Comment: Port 465 is usually for SSL (so `smtpClient.EnableSsl` should be `true`)... for port 25 it should be `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableSsl` should be true.
If you need a timeout  then its property should be set before the email is sent try adjusting like this

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
smtpClient.Port = 465;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = 
          new NetworkCredential("mailadress@server.net", "Password");

...
smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Since the default is to wait an infinite length of time this seems like it doesn't answer the question. Could you clarify while a shorter timeout will make it connect?

Comment: Hello! thanks dear for your reply. But it give me new error "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at Form1.Mailing()."

Comment: @user814064: you are right dear. Shorter time doesn't make any difrent accept change error text. I think the problem is in Goddady SMTP server. We need some solution for that. It is possible I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I say my previous C# working code (that was sending emails using Godaddy server) wasn't sending emails anymore. So I spend 5 hours to find the actual problem

**The problem is that Godaddy** changed the settings on their servers. Due to this you won't be able to send email using:

1. "smtpout.secureserver.net" host.
2. local host (local system).

**I solved this by doing 2 things:**

1. Used SmtpClient Host as "relay-hosting.secureserver.net".
2. Put my web page on my Godaddy shared server (as localhost will still not able to send smtp email due to security added by Godaddy).

This is the **correct working code** from my side:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@yourdomain.com");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("senderemail@gmail.com"));

mailMessage.Subject = "hello";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Body = "hello how are you";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@yourdomain.com", "yourpassword");
client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

In the above code see how **I added the host**:

```
client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
```

The mail will reach you in 25 to 30 seconds time. If you still can't find the email kindly check your spam folder.

**Proof**

At the time of writing this answer I tested my code and found the send email to my Gmail Inbox. See the below image as a proof:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the code below. You have to change `client.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net."`

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(txtemail.Text, "shopover@vibrantinfosystems.com");
msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
string body = "Name: " + txtname.Text.Trim() + "";
body += "<br />Email:" + txtemail.Text + "";
body += "<br /><br /> Subject :" + txtsubject.Text + "";
body += "<br /><br />Message : " + txtmessage.Text + "";
msg.Body = body;

msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net.";

client.Send(msg);
client.Timeout = 10000;
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Mail Sent Successfully!!');", true);
```

Comment: smtpout.secureserver.net is abandoned by Godaddy now use "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" instead.